# Java 8 - Hashmap cannot find and return a ZonedDateTime value

Tags: java, java-8, zoneddatetime

I'm working on a example project where we need to store some values in a Hashmap and fetch them via REST services.

POSTing the data as

```
{"timestamp":"2015-09-01T16:40:00.000Z", "temperature":"27.2"}
```

Save method:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> createCalc(@Valid @RequestBody Calc calc) {
   store.add(measurement);
}
...
```

Store class

```
private HashMap<ZonedDateTime, Calc> calcHashMap;
...
public void add(Calc calc) {
  calcHashMap.put(calc.getTimestamp(), calc);
}
```

After saving we wanted to get data from Hashmap, none of the below can find it.

```
http://localhost:8000/measurements/2015-09-01T16:40:00.000Z
or 
http://localhost:8000/measurements/2015-09-01T16:40Z
```

Method we are using is

```
  @GetMapping("/{timestamp}")
  public ResponseEntity<Calc> getCalc(@PathVariable ZonedDateTime timestamp) {

  Calc calc = process.fetch(timestamp);
```

Process.java class

```
 public Calc fetch(ZonedDateTime timestamp) {
    return calcMap.get(timestamp);
 }
```

Adding that to a Hashmap and Timestamp as the key. We are seeing these differences:

1. When printing the value in console using System.out.println **2015-09-01T16:40Z**
2. Return from REST GET method in POSTMAN shows this **2015-09-01T16:40:00Z**
3. While the actual value is **2015-09-01T16:40:00.000Z**

I need to find the stores timestamp and return the object, but is not being found because of the differences above. How to solve this?

Comment: I guess for `.` character your requestMapping was broke. so try use this `@GetMapping("/{timestamp:.+}")`

Comment: Thanks. Seeing the same empty response. Cannot find.

Comment: You are putting the value in `Store.java` and accessing from `Process.java`. Can you be clear?

Answer (score 0):

After some research i was able to solve this as below

```
for (ZonedDateTime zdt : measurementHashMap.keySet()) {
  if (timestamp.toInstant().compareTo(measurementHashMap.get(zdt).getTimestamp().toInstant()) == 0) {
     return measurementHashMap.get(zdt);
  }
}
```

Option 2:
There is another option to convert ZonedDateTime to OffSetDate and then compare. Ref: https://rextester.com/SIIIW97667

Comment: Then, why don’t you use the `Instant` as map key in the first place? Besides that, if you stick to the loop, why don’t you iterate over the [`values`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()), as the only thing you do with the key, is looking up the value.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Calc` class, you can use `@JsonFormat` from Jackson library and give the required pattern you want. In this case, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX". Also, I suggest you to use `OffsetDateTime` directly instead of conversion.